# Persisting string array in single column

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Our main domain object has multiple string[] properties (various configuration options) and we are thinking of an elegant way to persist the data. GORM creates joined table for the each array so we end up with about dozen joined tables.

I wonder if it would be possible to serialize each array into single column of the main table (someway delimited) and parse it back into array onload?

Do you have suggestions how to do this? I'm thinking either hibernate usertype or grails property editor? I spent some time with usertypes but without luck.

thanks
pk

Comment: Out of interest, is there a problem with the dozens of tables that GORM is creating?

Answer (score 1):

you could put the parameters into a map / array, then store them in a db field as Json:

```
def someDomainInstance = new SomeDomain()
def paramMap = [name:'John', age:24]
someDomainInstance.paramJson = paramMap as JSON
someDomainInstance.save()
```

Then you can easily convert this string back to a map / array when you interrogate the DB:

```
def paramMapFromDB = JSON.parse(someDomainInstance.paramJson)
assertEquals 24, paramMapFromDB.age
```

Something like that, I haven't tested the syntax, but that's the general idea.